# pulling timediff from created columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working on a MySQL query to return some specific results.  I am very close.  Now, I need to calculate the TIMEDIFF between 2 of the columns.  Here is my current query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%W') DAY, MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'ClockIn' THEN DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%r') END) AS 'Clock In', MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'BreakOut' THEN 
    DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%r') END) AS 'Break Out', MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'BreakIn' THEN DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%r') END) 'Break In', MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'ClockOut' THEN 
    DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%r') END) 'Clock Out', TIMEDIFF('Clock In', 'Break Out') AS Total FROM timeclock_punchlog WHERE EmpID = 456 GROUP BY 
    DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%W') ORDER BY PunchDateTime;
```

Now, Total is showing 00:00:00.  Any ideas how I can do this?
Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling and tinkering around, I figured it out.  I found out you cannot use aliases created earlier in the query in the TIMEDIFF function.  I basically had to use the whole formula I used to create the alias in place of the alias in the TIMEDIFF function.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%W') DAY, MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'ClockIn' THEN DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%T') END) AS 'Clock In', MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'BreakOut' THEN DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%T') END) AS 'Break Out', MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'BreakIn' THEN DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%T') END) 'Break In', MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'ClockOut' THEN DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%T') END) 'Clock Out', (TIMEDIFF(MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'clockout' THEN DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%T') END), MAX(CASE WHEN PunchEvent = 'breakin' THEN DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%T') END))) AS Total FROM timeclock_punchlog WHERE EmpID = 456 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(PunchDateTime, '%W') ORDER BY PunchDateTime;
```

I also had to change my %r to %T so it would calculate the TIMEDIFF correctly based off a military time instead of a standard AM/PM time.
Hope this helps someone!
Mike